# How to refer --cli-input-json file in gitlab from jenkins

Tags: amazon-web-services, jenkins, amazon-ecs

I have a task definition json file required to create task definition in AWS ECS. taskdefinition.json file is available in gitlab.

How can i refer to the same file in my Jenkinsfile to create the task definition?

`aws ecs register-task-definition --cli-input-json`

Answer (score 0):

Within the Jenkins file any shell commands you run will be started from the root of the workspace.

If the file in question is within this workspace you can refer to it normally using a relative path within the workspace.

Otherwise you will need to take a look at in your Jenkinsfile downloading it from the remote source to the local disk, then running the above command referencing the new source on disk.

You can specify the local file name like so

```
aws ecs register-task-definition --cli-input-json file://path/to/file.json
```

Comment: my json file is present within the same repository and same hierarchy level as the jenkins file , could you please tell should how to give the relative path to the same from within the jenkins file.  i am new to all those hence sorry if i am asking basic questions

Comment: I have added to the answer how to do this :)

Comment: Thanks...I tried this..and I am getting following error now :(                          
 Parameter validation failed:
Missing required parameter in input: "family"
Missing required parameter in input: "containerDefinitions"
Unknown parameter in input: "taskDefinition", must be one of: family, taskRoleArn, executionRoleArn, networkMode, containerDefinitions, volumes, placementConstraints, requiresCompatibilities, cpu, memory              Any idea how to resolve this